# JmsTemplate's browseSelected not retrieving all messages

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

I have some Java code that reads messages from an ActiveMQ queue. The code uses a JmsTemplate from Spring and I use the "browseSelected" method to retrieve any messages from the queue that have a timestamp in their header older than 7 days (by creating the appropriate criteria as part of the messageSelector parameter).

```
    myJmsTemplate.browseSelected(myQueue, myCriteria, new BrowserCallback<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer doInJms(Session s, QueueBrowser qb) throws JMSException {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final Enumeration<Message> e = qb.getEnumeration();
            int count = 0;
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                final Message m = e.nextElement();
                final TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) MyClass.this.jmsQueueTemplate.receiveSelected(
                        MyClass.this.myQueue, "JMSMessageID = '" + m.getJMSMessageID() + "'");

                myMessages.add(tm);
                count++;
            }

            return count;
        }
    });
```

The BrowserCallback's "doInJms" method adds the messages which match the criteria to a list ("myMessages") which subsequently get processed further.

The issue is that I'm finding the code will only process 400 messages each time it runs, even though there are several thousand messages which match the criteria specified.

When I previously used another queueing technology with this code (IBM MQ), it would process all records which met the criteria.

I'm wondering whether I'm experiencing an issue with ActiveMQ's prefetch limit: http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html

Versions: ActiveMQ 5.10.1 and Spring 3.2.2.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Bear in mind that every JMS Queues implementations are different.
For example when using OAQ it's impossible to use custom criterias...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The broker will only return up to 400 message by default as configured by the [maxBrowsePageSize](http://activemq.apache.org/per-destination-policies.html) option in the destination policies.  You can increase that value but must use caution as the messages are paged into memory and as such can lead you into an OOM situation.

You must always remember that a message broker is not a database, using it as one will generally end in tears.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Looks like I'll have to rethink my approach to this code.